# libcouchbase connection errors

Tags: php, couchbase

Couchbase keeps complaining that I don't have a connection to Couchbase:

```
2013-10-28T11:15:46.580320-07:00 hoot77 apache2[30455]: PHP Warning:  There is no active     connection to couchbase in /ebs1/www/src/core/components/In/Couchbase/Bucket.php on line 112
```

The following is the piece of code that is trying to run, its a simple set.

```
*/
public function set($key, $doc, $try = 0) {

    // Make sure designDoc and dataView are set
    if(empty($this->designDoc) && empty($this->dataView)) {
        throw new In_Exception('Missing Design Doc and/or View name for Couchbase', 400);
    }

    try {
        $results = $this->cb->set($key, $doc);
    } catch(CouchbaseLibcouchbaseException $e) {
        // Connection not active, try to rebuild connection and query again

        // Log stats on exception
        Statsd::increment("web.Couchbase.Exception.LibCouchbaseException.{$this->instanceKey}");
        Logger::error("LibCouchbaseException on {$this->instanceKey}: {$e->getMessage()}");

        // Try to reconnect and query up to twice
        $try++;
        if($try <= 2) {
            $this->rebuildConnection();
            return $this->set($key, $doc, $try);
        } else {
            // Fail if we've already tried twice
            throw new In_Exception('Could not connect to Couchbase', 500);
        }

    } catch(CouchbaseException $e) { 
        // Catch general exception, try to determine cause

        // Log stats on exception
        Statsd::increment("web.Couchbase.Exception.CouchbaseException.{$this->instanceKey}");
        Logger::error("CouchbaseException on {$this->instanceKey}: {$e->getMessage()}");

        // Throw exception if design document or view not found
        if($this->getExceptionCode($e->getMessage()) == 404) {
            throw new In_Exception('Design Document, or View not found in Couchbase', 404);
        } else {
            throw new In_Exception('Error with Couchbase, try again.', 500);
        }

    }

    // Success, return results
    Statsd::increment("web.couchbase.{$this->instanceKey}.success");
    return $results;
}
```

The line that its complaining about is:

```
$results = $this->cb->set($key, $doc);
```

You can see that my quick solution was to try to reconnect up to twice on failure, but that doesn't seem to be helping at all, the errors still persist in great numbers.

It's actually not catching the exceptions and reporting them consistently either, which is annoying, because PHP is throwing these as warnings, not exceptions.

Let me know if you have any suggestions as to how to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you instantiate the couchbase (`$this->cb`) object? Are you sure it instantiates?

Comment: Thank you for your response, the connection is definitely instantiated in the constructor, and even if I use the Couchbase class itself (not my abstraction), the same errors occur. This seems to happen on long running processes? This is the best I can tell at this point.

Comment: Might be an issue with persistent connections http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/couchbase-php-sdk-persistent-connections